# Avoiding repeating lines by using infinite loop, is it good or bad?

Tags: c, loops

I'm studying C with K.N. King's C: A Modern Approach and there is a problem (Ch.06 - Prog. Project #4) which asks the reader to write a program that calculates broker's commission according to a trade until the amount of trade is 0.

Here is the writer's implementation:

```
float commission, value;

  printf("Enter value of trade: ");
  scanf("%f", &value);

  while (value != 0.0f) {
    if (value < 2500.00f)
      commission = 30.00f + .017f * value;
    else if (value < 6250.00f)
      commission = 56.00f + .0066f * value;
    else if (value < 20000.00f)
      commission = 76.00f + .0034f * value;
    else if (value < 50000.00f)
      commission = 100.00f + .0022f * value;
    else if (value < 500000.00f)
      commission = 155.00f + .0011f * value;
    else
      commission = 255.00f + .0009f * value;

    if (commission < 39.00f)
      commission = 39.00f;

    printf("Commission: $%.2f\n\n", commission);

    printf("Enter value of trade: ");
    scanf("%f", &value);
  }
```

But I thought rather than writing the printf and scanf lines twice, it'd be better to use an infinite `for` loop, like this:

```
float value, commission;

for (;;) {
    printf("Enter value of trade: ");
    scanf("%f", &value);
    if (value == 0)
        break;

    if (value < 2500)
        commission = 30.00f + 0.017 * value;
    else if (value < 6250)
        commission = 56.00f + 0.0066 * value;
    else if (value < 20000)
        commission = 76.00f + 0.0034 * value;
    else if (value < 50000)
        commission = 100.00f + 0.0022 * value;
    else if (value < 500000)
        commission = 155.00f + 0.0011 * value;
    else
        commission = 255.00f + 0.0009 * value;

    if (commission < 39.00f)
        commission = 39.00f;

    printf("Commission: %.2f\n", commission);
}
```

My question is, is taking account the number of lines and avoiding the repetition a good and necessary habit or is this a bad way in means of algorithm design?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ever learn about the `do-while` loop?

Comment: I'd never omit the `{ }` characters after an `if` or `else`.  Other than that, your second snippet seems just fine to me.  But that's my opinion only.  This is definitely an "opinion based" question, so I've voted to close it.  Also, I don't know why you tagged it with Java - this code is C.

Comment: And of course, you mustn't get into the habit of using `float` variables to store amounts of money.  There are very few cases in which this is a good idea.  If your book advises you to do this, then I would throw it away and buy a different book.

Comment: Sometimes, you need something between the start of the loop and loop condition check. This is one of those cases. That's perfectly fine. I call it a middle-tested loop.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Omitting the curly braces is based on the same reason as using the infinite for loop, for the sake of readability, which is I'm just trying to learn to do properly and the book does not encourage to use `float` all the time. It happens on occasion. Thank you for your opinions, by the way.

Comment: Regarding the comment you got about the do-while loop. I've once seen a colleague use a a construct considered harmful to force the code into a do-while loop, except the first iteration which he made "shorter". Compared to that, your conditional break is not at all bad.

Comment: Definitely.  A do-while would be considerably worse than the original while.  My opinion is that the "forever" loop with the conditional break is by far the best of the three, and it's really the only way to avoid repetition.  Some people prefer `while(1)` over `for(;;)` as a way of writing "forever".  Indeed, I have been downvoted in an answer to a Java question, for writing `for(;;)`.  But it's really a matter of preference.

Comment: Side issues:  1) Better code would check the return value of `scanf("%f", &value);` 2) Why `f` with `30.00f`, yet not `0.017`?

Comment: @chux What do you mean by the return value of `scanf("%f", &value);`. I'm a beginner, explain it to me please :) and I've no idea about the appendix of `f`. I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: `scanf();` return the number of fields successfully scanned.  which would be 1: a `float` was read, 0: only non-numeric input encountered like `"abc"`. Or `EOF` to indicate `stdin` is closed.

Answer (score 6):

Don't repeat yourself.  [DRY vs. WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).

Consider that the code needs re-work

```
// weak
printf("Enter value of trade: ");  
scanf("%f", &value);

// better
printf("Enter value of trade: ");  
fflush(stdout);   // Insure text is printed before scanning
if (scanf("%f", &value) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

Would a maintainer of the code like to update this in 1 or 2 places?

User I/O often benefits with a helper function and makes for a clear non-repetitive coded loop condition.

```
int read_double(const char *prompt, double *y, ) {
  printf("%s", prompt);  
  fflush(stdout);
  int count = scanf("%f", y);
  return count; 
}

while (read_double("Enter value of trade: ", &value) == 1) {
  if (value == 0)
  ...
  printf("Commission: %.2f\n", commission);
}
```

---

The whole `if()`, `else if()`, ... could use re-work too.  Perhaps `struct` is too new for OP, yet the point is that code evolves and coding for ease of maintenance is a very worthy goal.

```
  const struct {
    double value;
    double commission_base;
    double commission_rate;
  } tier[] = { 
    { 2500.00, 30.00, 0.017 }, 
    { 6250.00, 56.00, 0.0066 },
    { 20000.00, 76.00, 0.0034 }, 
    { 50000.00, 100.00, 0.0022 },
    { 500000.00, 155.00, 0.0011 }, 
    { DBL_MAX, 255.00, 0.0009 } };
  int n = sizeof tier / sizeof tier[0];
  double commission = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (value < tier[i].value) {
      commission = tier[i].commission_base + tier[i].commission_rate * value;
      break;
    }
  }
  #define COMMISSION_MIN 39.00
  if (commission < COMMISSION_MIN) {
    commission = COMMISSION_MIN;
  }
```

Comment: Tip: Coding often involves using a set of data, like OP's commission data.  I highly recommend to **not** code that data in-line as code, but maintain as a separate data structure.  A successful program needs to be correctly and easily updated to reflect a new commission schedule.

Answer (score 3):

One rule is *Don't Repeat Yourself*. As with any rule, there can be exceptions, but you should pay attention to it if you have no strong reason to go another way.

The rationale behind it is not really typing lazyness, but more that if you have to change code, you will have to take care of not forgetting one single occurence of repeated code.

For that reason, and even if in your example it is not far from a matter of taste, I definitely prefere the second version where code is not duplicated. A specific reason here is that you *really should* test the return value of `scanf` (what if the user erroneously types an alpha of symbol?). If the second version you have to fix the problem only once. In the first version, if you do that long time after writing it first, or even worse if someone else has to fix it, there is a risk forgetting one instance.

Comment: Thank you! Your approach shows the importance of making the code clearer since it does not just increases the readability, but also helps in editing and fixing it sometime later.

Answer (score 1):

Using an infinite loop to accomplish this task technically works. However, the suggested code is cleaner, as the condition to break out of the loop is inherent in the loop type. The [different loop types](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html) allow you to accomplish different tasks more efficiently. The "for" loop can increase or decrease the value of a variable without needing to write the code for this within the loop.  A while loop simply runs a check, which is what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, your answer makes the logic of loops very clean. Although I cannot agree with you on this specific problem, thank you for your meaningful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should heed the advice of the other responders about not using float for money. That said, here's a way to avoid using an infinite loop (still uses your float nomenclature, but you should change it as appropriate):

```
float value = 1.0;
while ( value != 0.0f ) {
   // prompt for input

   // get input

   if ( value > 0.0f ) {
      // handle the input and output resultshere
   }
}
```

Comment: This one is different than what I've encountered so far. I was stuck on `scanf`. It is meaningful and seems does not repeat the `scanf` and `printf ` lines. By the way, the `float` chocie was not up to me. It was writer's decision, so I just followed it on this particular problem but thank you for your warning!